# regarding displaying and saving 0-1 ndarrays into images

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, matplotlib, scipy

There exist a ndarray with shape (5508,1,64,80), which stores 5508 two dimensional 0-1 array corresponding to 5508 images. I am trying to save them into 5508 images with the following code segment.

```
import numpy as np
import os
image_path = "/data/image_test"

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cmp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    img_array = np.load('/data/imgs_mask_test.npy')
    print(img_array.shape)
    for i in range(img_array.shape[0]):
        file_name = os.path.join(image_path,'_'+str(i)+'.png')
        plt.imsave(file_name,img_array[i,0],cmap=cmp.gray)
```

I am not sure whether this code segment is right. I checked the generated images, which are all black. Does that mean all the values in the original ndarray are 0?From the perspective of numpy, can we get all the locations having entry value of 1?

Moreover, I am suspecting whether I need to re-scale this 0-1 to 0-255? But it seems to me that it will still just give me two values, e.g., 0 and 255.

The following is a just a screenshot from the windows file system.

[image]

Comment: Check the `.max()`, `.min()` values?

Comment: You could check your result by reading image ```_5408.png``` and comparing it to ```img_array[5408,1,:,:]``` - ```np.all(png_array == img_array[5408,1,:,:]```.  A few checks should give you a sense of whether your process was correct.

Comment: Why do you think that rescalling your values to 0--255 will give you only two values? if your original values are 0 or 1 than yes but if they are in the range 0-1 rescalling will give values in the range of 0-255.

Comment: I compute the max value and min value, it equals to 0.00170872779563 and 0.0 respectively. Does that indicate that there is very little variance for the pixel values. And they still look black even after rescaling.